# Can partial classes be used for web-services?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

Can partial classes be used for web-services or there is some other way to implement it ?

Comment: Clarify your question please. "Partial classes" is a compiler feature that allows you to split a class into different files. Such compile feature should also be available in webservices, because the webservice gets compiled as well

Comment: Check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226554/c-partial-classes-web-services-seperating-form-and-functionality

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial classes are a compiler feature shared by all of C#, so yes, you can use them for web services.

In fact, it is a feature that is has completely nothing to do with web-services. It simply allows you to split a class over more than one file.

If you want to do so with your web service, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can - in WCF, if a composite service exposes multiple contracts, we place the implementation .cs in separate partial classes for clarity.